# Fluid going through a surface even though it is an obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a problem with fluid going through an object even though I set it to be an *Obstacle*. I made a [video](https://youtu.be/5XAJZjvgvlM) explaining my problem.

Settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

.blend and other related files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzgDIjhDOu6EVEdWdE1HQng3ZlE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Aside: in case you don't know, you can Ctrl-click or double-click on an object's name to rename it within Blender, so that you can see your handy labels while you work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your *Obstacle* object, under *Properties panel> Physics > Fluid > Volume Initialization:*, select *Shell*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that sometimes helps is adding a "solidify" modifier to your object. This gives the object a thickness that can help with fluid aberrations. This modifier must be applied or at least above the other modifiers in the stack to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (object not interacting at all with the fluid, whereas primitives like a cube would interact correctly)

Turns out in my case *Export Animated Mesh* had to be checked on the obstacle object

[image: screenshot of fluid configuration with Export Animated Mesh checked]