# Fluid going through an obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation

I couldn't find an answer anywhere else, so I'm posting here. I have a fluid simulation that works well mostly, but it is going through part of an obstacle. This obstacle is a corridor that holds fluid, but two thirds down the way it just pours through the wall. It is all the same mesh. Image and .blend file included.[image: Rendered image of the problem.]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YJIbvaZd_Otu4WXngIhwV_7y7j1T_ehx

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50814/prevent-fluid-to-flow-through-the-walls-of-an-obstacle  or  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126702/fluid-simulation-leaking-through-obstacle  or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53651/fluid-going-through-a-surface-even-though-it-is-an-obstacle

Comment: Is the collider set to mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason here is clearly low resolution of the fluid. Just increase the resolution. If your mesh walls are thinner than the fluid simulation cells, this will happen.